# Swift addObject

Tags: arrays, json, swift

So, I'm learning how to get data from DB with JSON and then put the data on some array. Problem accours on last line, `citiesArray.addObject(City())`, when I need to put all data from object `city` (id, name, state,...) into array. 
I was looking line by line with compiler, and basically everything is fine except that at the end, my array is still empty (its value is `nil`)?

```
for (var i=0;i<jsonArray.count;i++){
    //Create city objec
    var cID: AnyObject? = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("id") as NSString
    var cName: AnyObject? = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("cityName") as NSString
    var cState: AnyObject? = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("cityState") as NSString
    var cPopulation: AnyObject? = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("cityPopulation") as NSString
    var cCountry: AnyObject? = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("country") as NSString

    //add city obj (i have City class) to city array
    var city = City()

    city.cityID = cID as NSString
    city.cityName = cName as NSString
    city.cityState = cState as NSString
    city.cityPopulation = cPopulation as NSString
    city.cityCountry = cCountry as NSString

    citiesArray.addObject(City())
}
```

Comment: The last line should probably be `citiesArray.addObject(city)` ...

Comment: I have tried City(), city, City, city.cityName, City().cityName. Nothing worked.

Comment: Where is `citiesArray` declared? Where/how is it initialized?

Comment: Where is it *initialized*?

Comment: I have declared it on the begining of code (before viewDidLoad) ->    var citiesArray: NSMutableArray!

Comment: That line doesn't init the array.  That only declares it.  First you have to init it like so: `citiesArray = NSMutableArray()`, then you can add to it the way @MartinR posted.

Comment: Show us your line that initializes `citiesArray`. By the way, if this is Swift array, one generally uses `citiesArray.append(city)`, not `citiesArray.addObject(city)`.

Comment: Actually I wonder why your code does not crash. If citiesArray is only *declared* as `NSMutableArray!` and not initialized, then `citiesArray.addObject(...)` should crash (in contrast to Objective-C where just nothing would happen).

Comment: Im sry, havent copy all. It is var citiesArray: NSMutableArray! = [] and I have tried with append, but then I get an error "NSMutableArray does not have a member named 'append'"

Comment: @rFessler I puted this into code now, and still nothing. jsonArray array is filled with data, but cities is not. There is no errors, just some list without any data

Comment: Hmm...i dont know why, but when I put this code into Playground, everything seems to be all right. I right panel i see populated array

Comment: You want `var citiesArray = NSMutableArray()` which will instantiate the `NSMutableArray`. Your syntax will define the variable, but not create the `NSMutableArray` object. By using `var citiesArray = NSMutableArray()` syntax, we're both defining the variable as well as instantiating the mutable array.

Comment: You should check out SwiftyJSON it makes parsing JSON 100% easier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. You suggested that you were trying to add the city with the following line of code:

   ```
   citiesArray.addObject(City())
   ```

   The `City()` construct will instantiate a new, blank `City` object. So that line of code would, best case scenario, add a blank `City` object to your array, which is not what you intended.

   When you add the `city` to your `citiesArray`, you should simply:

   ```
   citiesArray.addObject(city)
   ```
2. You say you've defined your `citiesArray` like so:

   ```
   var citiesArray: NSMutableArray!
   ```

   You also need to instantiate an object for this variable (i.e. create an object to which this variable will now point), e.g.:

   ```
   citiesArray = NSMutableArray()
   ```
3. You are reporting, though, that at the end of this loop, that `citiesArray` is `nil`. Really?!? But if you tried to call the `addObject` method and `citiesArray` was `nil`, you could have received a fatal error: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

   So, if `citiesArray` was `nil`, then `jsonArray` must have been empty, too. Or for some reason you didn't even get to this loop. I would suggest (a) logging `jsonArray`; and (b) log or put breakpoint inside this loop and confirm you're even getting in here like you think you are.

   Also, check the timing of this (i.e. make sure your statement logging `citiesArray` is actually taking place *after* this routine that populates it). I know that sounds crazy, but if you are retrieving the data from some network resource asynchronously, you could have some timing related issues.
4. Since you're writing Swift code, you might consider using Swift arrays. For example, define your  array variable as

   ```
   var citiesArray: [City]!
   ```

   And instantiate it with:

   ```
   citiesArray = [City]()
   ```

   And add objects to it with:

   ```
   citiesArray.append(city)
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I have forgot to add citiesArray() for instantiate, and I have put "City()" exept of "city" so that was mistake too. Now its everything working nice!

Comment: good one, I was trying to append the array of strings instead of Object array. Your answer helped !

Answer (score 6):

I am pretty sure you need to use the append function:

```
 citiesArray.append(city)
```

or

if you want to append at the start of the array

```
 citiesArray.insert(city, atIndex: 0)
```

instead of

```
citiesArray.addObject(City())
```

here is a little example: Syntax might not be 100% not on comp with xcode right now.

```
 var strA:String = "apple"
 var strB:String = "pineapple"

 var strArr = ["kiwi", "mango", "lime"]

 strArr.append(strA)
 println(strArr.count) //4 ["kiwi", "mango", "lime", "apple"]


 citiesArray.insert(strB, atIndex: 0)
 println(strArr.count) //5 ["pineapple", "kiwi", "mango", "lime", "apple"]
```